# Rails 4 autocomplete not updating association field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, associations, multi-select

I use the rails-4-automplete gem which works nicely with simple_form to autocomplete the "name" field of my model. It also updates other fields when an existing record is found except a multiple select field that is populate from a HABTM association.

```
<% f.association role, collection: Roles.all, prompt: "Choose a role" %>
```

I have set the user_params including `role_ids: []`

Is there a way to populate this field through the association using the update_field and extra_data options of the gem?